# Single Facebook App on multiple domains

Tags: facebook

I am developing a product for a business, which has *n* clients, each one with its own website.

Now, what the product does is **injecting our Facebook App into the Client's Website**, to allow the Client's customers to login and share things on Facebook, with our app.

Facebook prevents this because the site url is different from the one specified in the dashboard.

So, how can we structure the product to allow this kind of usage?